map(object) with list(string) in terraform
We have several glue workflows. Within each workflow we have several triggers and within each trigger we have several jobs. I would like to use map(object) for the requirement.
  variable "gluetriggers_jobs" {
  type = map(object({
    trigger_name                = string
    workflow_name               = string
    trigger_type                = string
    job_name                    = list(string)

  }))
  }

gluetriggers_jobs = {
  trig_wklt_ChangeData_Capture_00 = {
      trigger_name    = "trig_wklt_ChangeData_Capture_00"
      workflow_name   = "wklt_ChangeData_Capture"
      trigger_type    = "ON_DEMAND"
      job_name        = ["m_opty_cdc_1",
                         "m_opty_cdc_2"
                             ]
          },
     trig_wf_Sil_Day_Dimension_01 = {
      trigger_name    = "trig_wf_Sil_Day_Dimension_01"
      workflow_name   = "wf_Sil_Day_Dimension"
      trigger_type    = "ON_DEMAND"
      job_name        = ["m_opty_cdc_3",
                         "m_opty_cdc_4",
                         "m_opty_cdc_5",
                         "m_opty_cdc_6",
                         "m_opty_cdc_7",
                         "m_opty_cdc_8",
                         "m_opty_cdc_9",
                         "m_opty_cdc_10"
                             ]
          }
    

    }

locals {
  glue_trigger_jobs = flatten([
   for trigger_key, trigger in var.gluetriggers_jobs : [
      for j_name_key, jname in trigger.job_name: {
               trigger_name    = trigger_key
               workflow_name   = trigger.workflow_name
               trigger_type    = trigger.trigger_type
               job_name        = jname
                 
               } 
               
      ]
])
}


module "glue_trigger_jobs" {

  for_each = var.gluetriggers_jobs

  source = "../modules/glue-trigger"

  trigger_name                  = "${var.application}.${var.environment}.${each.value.trigger_name}"
  workflow_name                 = "${var.application}.${var.environment}.${each.value.workflow_name}"
  trigger_type                  =  each.value.trigger_type
  #job_name                      = "${var.application}.${var.environment}.${each.value.job_name}"

 actions = [
    {
      job_name = "${var.application}.${var.environment}.${each.value.job_name}"
      
    }
  ]

  }

resource "aws_glue_trigger" "MAS_glue_triggers" {
  name                             = var.trigger_name
  type                             = var.trigger_type
  workflow_name                    = var.workflow_name
  enabled                          = var.trigger_enabled

  predicate {
    conditions {
      job_name         = var.predicate_job_name
      state            = var.predicate_state
      logical_operator = var.predicate_logical_operator
    }
    logical = var.predicate_logical
  }
  actions {
    job_name = var.job_name
  }
} 
}


This gives me a flat list and i do not want that. I should be able to loop through triggers and create trigger and attach workflows to the trigger. The code should also attach the jobs to the triggers. The workflows are already created.
